# OpenConnect (ocserv) Connected on client side, But Can not open any web page (NO INTERNET)

Tags: vpn, centos, cisco-anyconnect

Please take a look at these links :
[openconnect / ocserv](https://github.com/openconnect/ocserv)
[openconnect / ocserv Installation - CentOS, RHEL, Fedora](https://ocserv.gitlab.io/www/recipes-ocserv-installation-CentOS-RHEL-Fedora.html)
I have centos 7.6 as server with **public ip**.
Also in client machine i have windows 7 os with wireless internet.
I followed these commands to install openconnect on server machine :

```
sudo yum -y install gnutls-devel libev-devel tcp_wrappers-devel pam-devel lz4-devel libseccomp-devel readline-devel libnl3-devel krb5-devel radcli-devel
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum repolist enabled
sudo yum info ocserv
sudo yum -y install ocserv
sudo ocpasswd -c /etc/ocserv/ocpasswd test
123
nano -K /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf
```

And here is ocserv.conf file :

```
auth = "plain[passwd=/etc/ocserv/ocpasswd]"

tcp-port = 8090
udp-port = 8090

run-as-user = ocserv
run-as-group = ocserv

socket-file = ocserv.sock

chroot-dir = /var/lib/ocserv

isolate-workers = true

max-clients = 5

max-same-clients = 1

keepalive = 32400

dpd = 90

mobile-dpd = 1800

switch-to-tcp-timeout = 25

try-mtu-discovery = true

server-cert = /etc/pki/ocserv/public/server.crt
server-key = /etc/pki/ocserv/private/server.key

ca-cert = /etc/pki/ocserv/cacerts/ca.crt

cert-user-oid = 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1

tls-priorities = "NORMAL:%SERVER_PRECEDENCE:%COMPAT:-VERS-SSL3.0"

auth-timeout = 240

min-reauth-time = 300

max-ban-score = 50

ban-reset-time = 300

cookie-timeout = 300

deny-roaming = false

rekey-time = 172800

rekey-method = ssl

use-occtl = true

pid-file = /var/run/ocserv.pid

device = vpns

predictable-ips = true

default-domain = example.com

ipv4-network = 192.168.102.0
ipv4-netmask = 255.255.255.0

dns = 8.8.8.8
dns = 8.8.4.4

ping-leases = false

cisco-client-compat = true

dtls-legacy = true

user-profile = profile.xml

# Routes to be forwarded to the client. If you need the
# client to forward routes to the server, you may use the 
# config-per-user/group or even connect and disconnect scripts.
#
# To set the server as the default gateway for the client just
# comment out all routes from the server, or use the special keyword
# 'default'.

#route = 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0
#route = 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
#route = fef4:db8:1000:1001::/64
```

After editing ocserv.conf i did these commands :

```
sudo systemctl start ocserv
sudo systemctl enable ocserv
sudo systemctl status ocserv
```

Now i downloaded gui software from [here](https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect-gui) on client machine.
Client machine can connect to openconnect with username `test` successfully.
But the problem is that i can not open any web page on client machine & it seems there is `NO INTERNET`.
What should i do on server machine to fix this problem?

---

Firewall is off on both server & client.
I did nothing about routing or forwarding.
I am not familiar with them.
If necessary tell me what should i do about them?
Also i found this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/851035/connected-to-openvpn-but-no-internet-connection) about my situation. But not satisfy...

Comment: SilverLight - How about you try this.... add `route = default` for the route, then run the `sudo systemctl restart ocserv` & then test accordingly. Otherwise look over https://ocserv.gitlab.io/www/manual.html & understand the config file settings a little better for your needs & configure accordingly. I've never use `ocserv` but it sounds like you may have it configured to not route properly. I'd run `tracert` commands while both connected & disconnected from the VPN & read about the configs, make a change, test more, compare, etc. Dig, dig, & then dig some more—Backup your config file 1st.

Comment: are you able to ping server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have to add iptables/firewall for MASQUERADE 
this Firewall rules will make ur server  NAT Translator

```
iptables -A INPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables  -A INPUT -p udp -m udp -i eth0 --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
iptables  -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
iptables  -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.102.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score -2):

Turn On firewall , and allow the ports 8090 on both udp/tcp